# My MediaWiki {{See also}} returns "Template must be given at least one article name"

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

The error is found [here](http://wiki.gamepaduniverse.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=Gamepad_App_Lib)

I am trying to incorporate the See Also template on my wiki. I believe my usuage is correct. I just can't identify the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the [ParserFunctions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions) extension.

Comment: That was it. I messed around with the /extension/ParserFunctions extension so it was behaving improperly. I reinstalled the extension and now it works well.